# How to know if a stock is being held short

Tags: shorting-securities

Redditors successfully [attack hedge funds](https://www.theedgemarkets.com/article/hedgefund-legends-lose-billions-reddit-traders-running-amok) because they know that GME is being held short by them. But how do they know this? Where do they get this information?

According to [older posts](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/22112/how-do-we-know-the-number-of-shorted-shares-of-a-stock), you can check the number of short interest on [NASDAQ's site](https://www.nasdaq.com). However, GME is not listed on NASDAQ, so we can't check like this. So where do redditors get the required information to beat hedge funds?

Comment: Similar question, just yesterday: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135521/how-did-the-wallstreetbet-community-know-that-game-stop-was-shorted-so-heavily

Comment: Welcome new user.  Guys there is NO NEED to downvote new users with dupes, just send it to the dupe.  This web site is literally the best source of information for the zillions of folks asking about the Game Stop Thrills.  Try to act with .. gravitas!

Comment: Other posting: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/60794/without-bloomberg-how-can-retail-investors-know-how-many-shares-have-been-short

Comment: Not a downvoter, on this question, btw.

Comment: Thanks for all the information, GME is indeed the motivation for me to learn more about stock market.